# xmlParseMemory of libxml2 returns strange xmlDocPtr

Tags: xml, libxml2

I use libxml2 in order to parse an xml buffer. First I call the xmlParseMemory function in order to create the xmlDocPtr document, and later I call the getnodeset function in order to get the node that I need.
The problem is in the creation of the xmlDocPtr document, we suppose that we have an xml buffer like this:

I call the xmlParseMemory, so the xmlDocPtr is created, I accede for example to the first CONTENT node, I find that his first children is of type XML_TEXT_NODE and his name is "text"  and his next children is of type " XML_ELEMENT_NODE " and his name is "label". So the first children does not much my xml buffer.
And that is applicable for all the document, always the first children of each node  is an XML_TEXT_NODE whose name is "text". So, that disturbs my parsing.

I wonder why do I get a such result??

Regards.

Comment: this is the xml buffer:
<Drawing idTemplate="44" description="" name="NewChart"><CONTENT>
<label>
 <CONTENT type="title">
  <XML_VALUE name="TPVarValue" type="expression">
    <![CDATA[New Dynamic Chart]]></XML_VALUE>
   </CONTENT>
  </label>
  <label>
   <CONTENT type="xaxis">
    <XML_VALUE name="TPVarValue" type="expression">
     <![CDATA[Categories]]></XML_VALUE>
   </CONTENT>
  </label>
  <label>
   <CONTENT type="yaxis">
    <XML_VALUE name="TPVarValue" type="expression">
     <![CDATA[Values]]></XML_VALUE>
   </CONTENT>
  </label>
 </CONTENT>         
</Drawing>

Answer (score 0):

I understand why do I get a such result. It's because I have space and line break between XML tag. So to avoid a such problem the xml buffer or the xml file  must not contain any space or line breaks between tags.

Regards.